# CakePHP 3.8 Change Form Data based on User Selection

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, wamp

I am in CakePHP 3 environment in which I am on an Edit Action in the Articles Controller.

First Function on the controller is a standard edit function.. 
This loads existing data for the Article in a form so you can easily edit them.

```
public function edit($id){

    $article_categories = $this->Articles->Articlecats->find('list');
    $this->set('article_categories', $article_categories);

    $article = $this->Articles->get($id);

    // if you are not just landing on page but making the save 
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {

        // disable entity creation, not entirely sure what this does.. 
        $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());

        // Set the user_id from the session.
        $article->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

        if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {

            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);

        }

        // check if there are errors in editing and print them
        if ($article->getErrors()){

            // Entity failed validation 
            // print_r($article->getErrors());
            $this->Flash->error(__('Please correct values and try again.'));                

        }

    $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));

    }

    $this->set('article_pass', $article);    

}
```

The view in the edit method of the ArticlesController shows input fields in which you can edit Article information and then Save them to the underlying database. On the bottom of the View there is a button "button to check Functionality", which accesses a method on the ArticlesController through Ajax call. The function editcategory() on the ArticlesController retrieves information about the selected category and then returns a rendered view based on this information back.

On clicking this button I load the category and category information into a new form on screen.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'); ?> 

<!-- File: templates/Articles/edit.php -->

<h1>Edit Article</h1>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create($article_pass);
    echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['type' => 'hidden']);
    echo $this->Form->control('title');
    echo $this->Form->control('body', ['rows' => '3']);
    echo $this->Form->select('articlecat_id', $article_categories, ['id' => 'article_cat']);     
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Save Article'));
    echo $this->Form->end();

    $csrfToken = $this->request->getParam('_csrfToken');

    // self written element in View 
    // echo $this->articlecatCreate->create();

?>

<button id="edit_category">Button to check functionality</button>

<div id="ajax_data"></div>


<script>

    var csrf_token = <?php echo json_encode($csrfToken) ?>;  

    $(window).load(function() {   

        // get article category data from controller method through ajax call 
        // populate the form with them      
        $('#edit_category').click(function(){

            var targeturl = "http://wampprojects/composer_cakephptut/articles/editcategory"; 

            var category_selected = $('#article_cat').children("option:selected").val();
            console.log(category_selected);

            // need to check if this statement works?? 
            if ($('#article_cat').children("option:selected").val()){

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: targeturl,
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': csrf_token},
                    data: {category: category_selected},
                    success: function(result){

                        console.log(result);

                        // create a form with a POST action that links to database 
                        $('#ajax_data').html(result);


                    }
                });

            }else{

                console.log("no cat selected");

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The "editcategory()" method in the Articles Controller.

```
public function editcategory(){

    $this->loadModel('Articlecats');    

    $category_id = $this->request->getData('category'); 
    $articlecat_data = $this->Articlecats->get($category_id);
    $this->set('articlecat_pass', $articlecat_data);

    debug($articlecat_data);

    $this->render('element/articlecatcreate', 'ajax'); 

}
```

In the editCategory() method of the ArticlesController I retrieve information on the selected category. I then render a helper view called "articlecatcreate" that relies on the data I retrieved.

```
<h1>Edit ArticleCategory</h1>
<div>
    <?php echo $articlecat_pass['id'] ?>
    <?php echo $articlecat_pass['title'] ?>    

    <?php
    // you miss a primary key, it does try to save to the right table 
    echo $this->Form->create($articlecat_pass);
    echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['type' => 'hidden']);
    echo $this->Form->control('title');
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Save Article'));
    echo $this->Form->end();

    ?>

</div>
```

It correctly loads the Article Category data in the new part of the view that is added to the existing view through the method "$('#ajax_data').html(result);" in the ajax success function.

On saving the category I am trying to edit, I get the following error..
ERROR : "Record not found in table "articlecats" with primary key [NULL]"

So my newly created form that is added to the view tries to save on the correct table and model, but does not somehow load the key in the create method of the form..

How can I proceed?

**SOLUTION FOUND**

I found the solution in setting the controller and action in the form->create method $options parameters.

So the code for the element you render needs to be:

```
<h1>Edit ArticleCategory</h1>

<div>

    <?php

    // you miss a primary key, it does try to save to the right table 
    echo $this->Form->create($articlecat_pass, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Articlecats', 'action' => 'edit']]);
    echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['type' => 'hidden']);
    echo $this->Form->control('title');
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Save Article'));
    echo $this->Form->end();

    ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually create new widgits—or any new DOM nodes—using javascript. Consider this jQuery snippet for a random project I have laying around:

```js
$(this).replaceWith(
    '<a class="remove" id="' + $(this).attr('id') 
        + '" href="' + webroot + 'shop/remove/' + $(this).attr('id') 
        + '" title="Remove item">' 
        + '<img src="' + webroot + 'img/icon-remove.gif" alt="Remove" />' +
    '</a>'
);
```

You can easily get a reference to your second form:

```js
$('form#id_of_form')
```

But still, I find all this fussing around in jQuery and javascript a bit tedious for building a populated form when Cake is just an ajax call away.

So your success function can be something like

```js
$('form#id_of_form').replaceWith(new_form_from_ajax_call);
```

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look at it later today and let you know how it goes..

Comment: Hey Don Drake, I updated the original question.. Got a lot further with the render() method, still get an error referring to the loaded category in the table..

Comment: I think the problem is, when editcategory() renders the form, it also become the action that will handle the form data on submission. This is the default behavior of Form::create(); it makes the current method the form action. So, on submission, the query in editcategory() runs, but the expected category_id value is null. Set the form's action to be the method you actually want to handle the posted data.

Comment: Don Drake, thank you for your help.. I found the solution and added it to the original question. Solution is in setting the controller and action in the $options parameters of the form create method..

Answer (score 0):

You could write your axaj call's success function to build the DOM elements from the json, then insert them in your form.

But I think an easier solution is to send your ArticleController::editcategory() data ($articlecat_data) to an element that will render the form elements you need.

Return this HTML to your ajax success function and have that function insert it into your form.

All the normal cake form conventions will be honored in this way and the post data later will be just what you need.

A little attention to the id and class attributes in both your original page and your ajax-returned snippet should make it easy to either swap out the whole form, just its inner-html or to add more inputs to the existing form.

So my specific answer to "CAN I USE CAKEPHP FORMHELPER TO DO SO" is yes.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean, so in fact this would give me two options..

Since I cannot create widgets from within JQuery, only create texts and links, option one would be to use a form that is already present on screen, load it with my newly acquired category data so I could further use this. I tried this approach by adding the following code to my AJAX call..

Result is that I succesfully populate the 'title' field in my second form, but when clicking on the "save Category" button, my data is saved to the original article instead of the article category, so the reference of the first form.

Is there any way I can access the reference (maybe through $id value?) of the second form from within jquery? So is there a way to change the Context of the Form from JQuery?

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: targeturl,
                headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': csrf_token},
                data: {category: category_selected},
                success: function(result){

                    console.log(result);

                    // POPULATE AN EXISTING FORM WITH NEW DATA AND TOGGLE DISPLAY VALUE! 
                    var article = JSON.parse(result); 

                    // you can populate existing form fields
                    // how can you access the form id field? 
                    // id = "article_cat_create"
                    $("#article_cat_create").val(article);
                    console.log(article[0]['title']);
                    $("#article_cat_title").val(article[0]['title']);                        

                    // which value do you need to set in formhelper?? 
                    $('#article_cat_create').css("display", "block");                        


                }
            });
```

If not I will go for the second method, which - if I correctly understand - creating a new form from scratch.